# C# Process exit on batch file status?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, process

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Process process=Process.Start(@"C:\Users\dalvi\Desktop\iisresetdaily.bat");

    if(process.ExitCode==0)
        SendMail("Sucesss in iisreset..", "bye"); // --> case 1
    else
        SendMail("Failed iisreset..", "bye"); // --> case 2
}
```

Edit : My `SendMail` method is working fine.

I've written `iisresetdaily.bat` file which is doing `iisreset /stop` and `iisreset /start`. When it executes successfully, I need to send success in `iisrest` mail `--> case 1`, otherwise 
`case 2`.

But when I edit the `.bat` file and put some random words so batch file is failing, but still
it's sending `case 1` mail meaning success in `iisreset`.

Am I doing wrong to check status of batch file using Process.ExitCode here?

If batch file failed, I need to send `case 2` failed `iisreset`.

Comment: This task *might* be accpmplished easier through the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)

Comment: @JensKloster I tried but there is not option to send a mail when task fails :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because your "batch file" may not be able to reset IIS or whatever buts it does complete execution properly and exit with success [ie statusCode=0].

Try to make your batch like:

```
@echo Started
--Some code that works
--Some code that surely fails [But not break the batch, as in calling external program]
@echo Finished
```

You will notice that though "Some code that surely fails", you still witness "Finish".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the .bat script is not providing any useful error code / exit code for you to check. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130273/cmd-and-bat-file-converting-return-code-to-an-error-message) might give you some useful information about how to set it up correctly.

Also, see [this question for info on terminating a batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error) when encountering an error.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wait the process for exit before you can use `ExitCode`:

```
using(var process=Process.Start(@"iisresetdaily.bat")) {
    process.WaitForExit();

    var message=
        0!=process.ExitCode
            ?"Failed iisreset .."
            :"Sucesss in iisreset ..";

    SendMail(message, "bye"); 
}
```

It would be better if you can provide the content of the batch file, that we can help to figure out why.

Comment: How can i check for Failed iisrest condition any scenario?

Comment: @VishwanathDalvi: `ExitCode` can be used. The problem probably in the batch file, or it would not return `0` while `iisreset` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking iisreset exit codes in the batch script and propagating them?

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202013they have an example showing that it will return an error code of 1 if it fails.

```
@echo off
IISRESET /STOP /NOFORCE
if errorlevel == 1 goto EXIT
copy %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1 d:\backup\W3SVC1
IISRESET /START
:EXIT
```